# Quiz in PHP, how to send a score with the mail form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, email

I have this quiz webpage created in PHP with some JavaScript code. It takes the input from the user (checked answers in the dropdown list), write them into another input box and uses the mail form to send the values from these input boxes to a specified email. It also checks the answers and gives the result in number of points with the click of the submit button (shows the result on the same page).

Problem #1:
I would like to be able to send the score in the mail form too. How could I do it?

Problem #2:
How could I pass the values from the dropdown list straight to the mail form to be sent later on with the click on submit (not to the input box as this code does now)?

Thanks for your help!

I habe not tried anything because I have no clue where to start. The way this quiz works out is the only way I have been able to come up with. I don´t have too much experience with coding, I am a beginner.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Quiz</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $message_sent = false;

            if (isset($_POST['answerq1']) && $_POST['answerq1'] != '')
            {
        
        
            //submit the form
            $Q1 = $_POST['answerq1'];
            $Q2 = $_POST['answerq2'];
            $Q3 = $_POST['answerq3'];
            $Q4 = $_POST['answerq4'];
            $Q5 = $_POST['answerq5'];
            $Q6 = $_POST['answerq6'];
            $Q7 = $_POST['answerq7'];
            $Q8 = $_POST['answerq8'];
            $Q9 = $_POST['answerq9'];
            $Q10 = $_POST['answerq10'];
            

            $messageSubject = $_POST['studentname'];
            $to = "example@example.com";
            $body = "";


           
            $body .= "Question 1: Your answer - ".$Q1. "*(A - CORRECT ANSWER)" . "\r\n".
            "1. What is the main purpose of the CPU? \n\nA. To process all the data and instructions \r\nB. To create PowerPoint presentations \r\nC. To provide power to the computer" ."\n\n" .
            "-----------------------------------".
            "\n\n";
            
            $body .= "Question 2: Your answer - ".$Q2. "*(True - CORRECT ANSWER)" . "\r\n".
            "The CPUs contain 100s of gold pins - some of these transmit data, others supply power to the CPU. \n\nA. True \r\nB. False" . "\n\n" .
            "-----------------------------------".
            "\n\n";
            
            $body .= "Question 3: Your answer - ".$Q3. "*(C - CORRECT ANSWER)" . "\r\n".
            "The CPU stands for: \n\nA. Central Process Unity \r\nB. Central Processing Utility \r\nC. C. Central Processing Unit" . "\n\n" .
            "-----------------------------------".
            "\n\n";

            $body .= "Question 4: Your answer - ".$Q4. "*(False - CORRECT ANSWER)" . "\r\n".
            "The RAM memory stands for Read Access Memory. \n\nA. True \r\nB. False" . "\n\n" .
            "-----------------------------------".
            "\n\n";

            $body .= "Question 5: Your answer - ".$Q5. "*(C - CORRECT ANSWER)" . "\r\n".
            "Which from below is NOT a component of the computer system? \n\nA. Sound card \r\nB. Hard drive \r\nC. Calculator" . "\n\n" .
            "-----------------------------------".
            "\n\n";
            
            $body .= "Question 6: Your answer - ".$Q6. "*(True - CORRECT ANSWER)" . "\r\n".
            "The difference between computer hardware and software is that the hardware is the parts that can be physically touched and seen and the software is the set of instructions. \n\nA. True \r\nB. False" . "\n\n" .
            "-----------------------------------".
            "\n\n";
            
            $body .= "Question 7: Your answer - ".$Q7. "*(B - CORRECT ANSWER)" . "\r\n".
            "The volatile memory is computer memory that requires power to maintain the stored information; it retains its content while powered on but when the power is interrupted, the stored data is quickly lost. Which one is an example of the volatile memory? \n\nA. ROM \r\nB. RAM \r\nC. Hard drive" . "\n\n" .
            "-----------------------------------".
            "\n\n";
            
            $body .= "Question 8: Your answer - ".$Q8. "*(A - CORRECT ANSWER)" . "\r\n".
            "What is the immediate access store used for? \n\nA. It holds the data and programs that the CPU currently needs \r\nB. It controls and monitors communications between the computer and any hardware attached \r\nC. It carries out calculations and logic operations" . "\n\n" .
            "-----------------------------------".
            "\n\n";

            $body .= "Question 9: Your answer - ".$Q9. "*(B - CORRECT ANSWER)" . "\r\n".
            "What is clock speed measured in? \n\nA. Cycles per minute \r\nB. Cycles per second \r\nC. Cycles per hour" . "\n\n" .
            "-----------------------------------".
            "\n\n";
 
            $body .= "Question 10: Your answer - ".$Q10. "*(C - CORRECT ANSWER)" . "\r\n".
            "What does the arithmetic and logic unit do? \n\nA. It controls and monitors communications between the computer and any hardware attached \r\nB. It holds the data and programs that the CPU currently needs \r\nC. It carries out calculations and logic operations" . "\n\n" .
            "-----------------------------------".
            "\n\n";
                        
            $headers = "From: marcindybka@marcindybka.com" . "\r\n";
            mail($to,$messageSubject,$body,$headers);
                $message_sent = true;
        }
        else{

        }           
        ?>
        
        
        <?php
            echo "Good luck in this Quiz!";

            if(!empty($_POST)) {
                $selected1 = $_POST['ans1'];
                $selected2 = $_POST['ans2'];
                $selected3 = $_POST['ans3'];
                $selected4 = $_POST['ans4'];
                $selected5 = $_POST['ans5'];
                $selected6 = $_POST['ans6'];
                $selected7 = $_POST['ans7'];
                $selected8 = $_POST['ans8'];
                $selected9 = $_POST['ans9'];
                $selected10 = $_POST['ans10'];
            
                $correct = 0;
            
                if ($selected1 == "q1AnswerA") {
                    $correct++;
                    echo "<p>Question 1 - Correct!</p>";
                } elseif ($selected1 == "q1") {
                    echo "<p>Question 1 - You forgot to answer this question!</p>";
                } else
                    echo "<p>Question 1 - Incorrect!</p>";

                if ($selected2 == "q2AnswerA") {
                    $correct++;
                    echo "<p>Question 2 - Correct!</p>";
                } elseif ($selected2 == "q2") {
                    echo "<p>Question 2 - You forgot to answer this question!</p>";
                } else
                echo "<p>Question 2 - Incorrect!</p>";
        
                if ($selected3 == "q3AnswerC") {
                    $correct++;
                    echo "<p>Question 3 - Correct!</p>";
                } elseif ($selected3 == "q3") {
                    echo "<p>Question 3 - You forgot to answer this question!</p>";
                } else
                    echo "<p>Question 3 - Incorrect!</p>";
                
                if ($selected4 == "q4AnswerB") {
                        $correct++;
                    echo "<p>Question 4 - Correct!</p>";
                } elseif ($selected4 == "q4") {
                    echo "<p>Question 4 - You forgot to answer this question!</p>";
                } else
                    echo "<p>Question 4 - Incorrect!</p>";

                if ($selected5 == "q5AnswerC") {
                        $correct++;
                    echo "<p>Question 5 - Correct!</p>";
                } elseif ($selected5 == "q5") {
                    echo "<p>Question 5 - You forgot to answer this question!</p>";
                } else
                    echo "<p>Question 5 - Incorrect!</p>";

                if ($selected6 == "q6AnswerA") {
                        $correct++;
                    echo "<p>Question 6 - Correct!</p>";
                } elseif ($selected6 == "q6") {
                    echo "<p>Question 6 - You forgot to answer this question!</p>";
                } else
                    echo "<p>Question 6 - Incorrect!</p>";

                if ($selected7 == "q7AnswerB") {
                        $correct++;
                    echo "<p>Question 7 - Correct!</p>";
                } elseif ($selected7 == "q7") {
                    echo "<p>Question 7 - You forgot to answer this question!</p>";
                } else
                    echo "<p>Question 7 - Incorrect!</p>";

                if ($selected8 == "q8AnswerA") {
                        $correct++;
                    echo "<p>Question 8 - Correct!</p>";
                } elseif ($selected8 == "q8") {
                    echo "<p>Question 8 - You forgot to answer this question!</p>";
                } else
                    echo "<p>Question 8 - Incorrect!</p>";

                if ($selected9 == "q9AnswerB") {
                        $correct++;
                    echo "<p>Question 9 - Correct!</p>";
                } elseif ($selected9 == "q9") {
                    echo "<p>Question 9 - You forgot to answer this question!</p>";
                } else
                    echo "<p>Question 9 - Incorrect!</p>";

                if ($selected10 == "q10AnswerC") {
                        $correct++;
                    echo "<p>Question 10 - Correct!</p>";
                } elseif ($selected10 == "q10") {
                    echo "<p>Question 10 - You forgot to answer this question!</p>";
                } else
                    echo "<p>Question 10 - Incorrect!</p>";
                    
                //here the result is displayed
                    echo "<p>You got $correct answers correct!</p>";    
            } 
            else {
                echo "<p>Please take the quiz.</p>";
            }   
            
                
        ?>
        <hr>
        <form action="nameofthisfile.php" method="post">

            <p><h3>1. What is the main purpose of the CPU?</p></h3>
            <p>A. To process all the data and instructions</p>
            <p>B. To create PowerPoint presentations</p>
            <p>C. To provide power to the computer</p>
            <select name="ans1" id="q1">
                <option value="q1">Your answer</option>
                <option value="q1AnswerA">Answer A</option>
                <option value="q1AnswerB">Answer B</option>
                <option value="q1AnswerC">Answer C</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button"  id=buttonans1 onclick="myFunctionQ1()" value="Save my answer">
            <input type="text" name="answerq1" id="q1ans">
            <br>
            <br>
            <hr>

            <p><h3>2. The CPUs contain 100s of gold pins - some of these transmit data, 
                      others supply power to the CPU.</p></h3>
            <p>True</p>
            <p>False</p>
            <select name="ans2" id="q2">
                <option value="q2">Your answer</option>
                <option value="q2AnswerA">True</option>
                <option value="q2AnswerB">False</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button"  id=buttonans2 onclick="myFunctionQ2()" value="Save my answer">
            <input type="text" name="answerq2" id="q2ans">
            <br>
            <br>
            <hr>

            <p><h3>3. The CPU stands for:</p></h3>
            <p>A. Central Process Unity</p>
            <p>B. Central Processing Utility</p>
            <p>C. Central Processing Unit</p>
            <select name="ans3" id="q3">
                <option value="q3">Your answer</option>
                <option value="q3AnswerA">Answer A</option>
                <option value="q3AnswerB">Answer B</option>
                <option value="q3AnswerC">Answer C</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button"  id=buttonans3 onclick="myFunctionQ3()" value="Save my answer">
            <input type="text" name="answerq3" id="q3ans">
            <br>
            <br>
            <hr>

            <p><h3>4. The RAM memory stands for “Read Access Memory”.</p></h3>
            <p>True</p>
            <p>False</p>
            <select name="ans4" id="q4">
                <option value="q4">Your answer</option>
                <option value="q4AnswerA">True</option>
                <option value="q4AnswerB">False</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button"  id=buttonans4 onclick="myFunctionQ4()" value="Save my answer">
            <input type="text" name="answerq4" id="q4ans">
            <br>
            <br>
            <hr>

            <p><h3>5. Which from below is NOT a component of the computer system?</p></h3>
            <p>A. Sound card</p>
            <p>B. Hard drive</p>
            <p>C. Calculator</p>
            <select name="ans5" id="q5">
                <option value="q5">Your answer</option>
                <option value="q5AnswerA">Answer A</option>
                <option value="q5AnswerB">Answer B</option>
                <option value="q5AnswerC">Answer C</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button"  id=buttonans5 onclick="myFunctionQ5()" value="Save my answer">
            <input type="text" name="answerq5" id="q5ans">
            <br>
            <br>
            <hr>

            <p><h3>6. The difference between computer hardware and software is that the 
                      hardware is the parts that can be physically touched and seen and the 
                      software is the set of instructions.</p></h3>
            <p>True</p>
            <p>False</p>
            <select name="ans6" id="q6">
                <option value="q6">Your answer</option>
                <option value="q6AnswerA">True</option>
                <option value="q6AnswerB">False</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button"  id=buttonans6 onclick="myFunctionQ6()" value="Save my answer">
            <input type="text" name="answerq6" id="q6ans">
            <br>
            <br>
            <hr>

            <p><h3>7. The volatile memory is computer memory that requires power to 
                      maintain the stored information; it retains its content while powered on 
                      but when the power is interrupted, the stored data is quickly lost. Which 
                      one is an example of the volatile memory?</p></h3>
            <p>A. ROM</p>
            <p>B. RAM</p>
            <p>C. Hard drive</p>
            <select name="ans7" id="q7">
                <option value="q7">Your answer</option>
                <option value="q7AnswerA">Answer A</option>
                <option value="q7AnswerB">Answer B</option>
                <option value="q7AnswerC">Answer C</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button"  id=buttonans7 onclick="myFunctionQ7()" value="Save my answer">
            <input type="text" name="answerq7" id="q7ans">
            <br>
            <br>
            <hr>

            <p><h3>8. What is the immediate access store used for?</p></h3>
            <p>A. It holds the data and programs that the CPU currently needs</p>
            <p>B. It controls and monitors communications between the computer and any 
                  hardware attached</p>
            <p>C. It carries out calculations and logic operations</p>
            <select name="ans8" id="q8">
                <option value="q8">Your answer</option>
                <option value="q8AnswerA">Answer A</option>
                <option value="q8AnswerB">Answer B</option>
                <option value="q8AnswerC">Answer C</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button"  id=buttonans8 onclick="myFunctionQ8()" value="Save my answer">
            <input type="text" name="answerq8" id="q8ans">
            <br>
            <br>
            <hr>

            <p><h3>9. What is clock speed measured in?</p></h3>
            <p>A. Cycles per minute</p>
            <p>B. Cycles per second</p>
            <p>C. Cycles per hour</p>
            <select name="ans9" id="q9">
                <option value="q9">Your answer</option>
                <option value="q9AnswerA">Answer A</option>
                <option value="q9AnswerB">Answer B</option>
                <option value="q9AnswerC">Answer C</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button"  id=buttonans9 onclick="myFunctionQ9()" value="Save my answer">
            <input type="text" name="answerq9" id="q9ans">
            <br>
            <br>
            <hr>

            <p><h3> 10. What does the arithmetic and logic unit do?</p></h3>
            <p>A.   It controls and monitors communications between the computer and any 
                    hardware attached</p>
            <p>B.   It holds the data and programs that the CPU currently needs</p>
            <p>C.   It caries out calculations and logic operations</p>
            <select name="ans10" id="q10">
                <option value="q10">Your answer</option>
                <option value="q10AnswerA">Answer A</option>
                <option value="q10AnswerB">Answer B</option>
                <option value="q10AnswerC">Answer C</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button"  id=buttonans10 onclick="myFunctionQ10()" value="Save my answer">
            <input type="text" name="answerq10" id="q10ans">
            <br>
            <br>
            <hr>

            <input type="text" name="studentname" id="sname" placeholder="Your name">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <script>
            function myFunctionQ1(){
                var q1ans = q1.options[q1.selectedIndex].text;
                document.getElementById("q1ans").value = q1ans; 
            }

            function myFunctionQ2(){
                var q2ans = q2.options[q2.selectedIndex].text;
                document.getElementById("q2ans").value = q2ans; 
            }

            function myFunctionQ3(){
                var q3ans = q3.options[q3.selectedIndex].text;
                document.getElementById("q3ans").value = q3ans; 
            }

            function myFunctionQ4(){
                var q4ans = q4.options[q4.selectedIndex].text;
                document.getElementById("q4ans").value = q4ans; 
            }

            function myFunctionQ5(){
                var q5ans = q5.options[q5.selectedIndex].text;
                document.getElementById("q5ans").value = q5ans; 
            }

            function myFunctionQ6(){
                var q6ans = q6.options[q6.selectedIndex].text;
                document.getElementById("q6ans").value = q6ans; 
            }

            function myFunctionQ7(){
                var q7ans = q7.options[q7.selectedIndex].text;
                document.getElementById("q7ans").value = q7ans; 
            }

            function myFunctionQ8(){
                var q8ans = q8.options[q8.selectedIndex].text;
                document.getElementById("q8ans").value = q8ans; 
            }

            function myFunctionQ9(){
                var q9ans = q9.options[q9.selectedIndex].text;
                document.getElementById("q9ans").value = q9ans; 
            }

            function myFunctionQ10(){
                var q10ans = q10.options[q10.selectedIndex].text;
                document.getElementById("q10ans").value = q10ans; 
            }
        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it would really help to somehow make the code a bit more readable and then I believe solutions for both of your problems would appear in front of you (or we may find it here).

**Quiz definition**

How about putting the questions and answers in one place. If you want to edit question/answers, you don't have to change the rest of the code.

```
// This is an array of questions. Key is the index of the question, value is the question as a string.
$questions = [
  0 => 'first question',
  1 => 'second question',
];

// This is an array, where key is the key of the question, and array is an array of possible answers for that question.

$answers = [
  0 => [
    0 => 'first answer for first question',
    1 => 'second answer for first question'
  ],
  1 => [
    0 => 'first answer for second question',
    1 => 'second answer for second question'
  ]
];

$correct = [
  0 => 1, //correct answer for question 0 is "second answer for the first question
  1 => 1 //correct answer for question 1 is "second answer for the second question
];
```

**Functions**

Don't be afraid of using functions in PHP. Notice how your code repeats itself in some parts; that calls for using functions, which are meant to do one single procedure.

If you have the quiz defined in arrays like in the example above, you can use a function to generate the HTML, another function to check results, yet another function to compute user's score and yet another function to create an e-mail body!

**Generating HTML**

```
function generateHtml($questions, $answers)
{
  // Start of the form
  echo '<form action="quiz.php" method="POST">';
  // Loop through all questions
  foreach ($questions as $questionIndex => $questionText) {
    // Question text
    echo '<label>' . $questionText . '</label><br>';
    // Start a <select> that will contain all possible answers
    echo '<select name="question[' . $questionIndex . ']">';
    // Loop through all answers of the current question
    foreach ($answers[$questionIndex] as $answerIndex => $answerText) {
      echo '<option value="' . $answerIndex . '">' . $answerText . '</option>';
    }
    // Close <select>
    echo '</select><br><br>';
  }
  // Add a field for the student's name
  echo '<label for="STUDENT_NAME">Your name:</label><br><input id="STUDENT_NAME" type="text" name="studentname" value=""><br><br>';
  // Submit button and that's it
  echo '<input type="submit"></form>';
}
```

**Score**

```
function computeScore($questions, $correct)
{
  // Start with score 0
  $score = 0;
  // Maximum score is the number of questions
  $maxScore = count($questions);
  
  // Loop through all questions in the quiz
  foreach ($questions as $questionIndex => $questionText) {
    // If user did not answer this question, jump to the next question
    if (!isset($_POST['question'][$questionIndex])) {
      continue;
    }
  
    // Save user's answer (which is answer index)
    $usersAnswer = intval($_POST['question'][$questionIndex]);
  
    // If correct answer index equals user's answer, increase the score
    if ($correct[$questionIndex] === $usersAnswer) {
      $score++;
    }
  }
  
  // Score output
  return sprintf('%d out of %d (%.2f %%)', $score, $maxScore, (($score * 100) / $maxScore));
}
```

**E-mail body**

```
function emailBody($questions, $answers, $correct) {
  // We start with empty body and build its text bit by bit
  $body = '';
  // Loop through all questions
  foreach ($questions as $questionIndex => $questionText) {
    // User's answer is -1, which means "did not answer"
    $usersAnswer = -1;

    // If the user did answer though, save the user's answer index
    if (isset($_POST['question'][$questionIndex])) {
      $usersAnswer = intval($_POST['question'][$questionIndex]);
    }
  
    // Now we save the correct answer index
    $correctAnswer = $correct[$questionIndex];
  
    // And add this text to the e-mail body
    $body .= sprintf(
      "Question %d: Your answer - %d *(%d - CORRECT ANSWER)\r\n%d. %s \n\n",
      $questionIndex,
      $usersAnswer,
      $correctAnswer,
      $questionIndex,
      $questionText
    );

    // Now we just add the text of all possible answers for that question
    foreach ($answers[$questionIndex] as $answerIndex => $answerText) {
      $body .= sprintf("%d. %s\r\n", $answerIndex, $answerText);
    }

    //Horizontal rule
    $body .= "-----------------------------------\n\n";
  }
  
  // To the end of the e-mail we just append the user's score
  $body .= "Your score: " . computeScore($questions, $correct, false);
  
  // Done!
  return $body;
}
```

**Report answers**

```
function htmlReport($questions, $correct)
{
  // Loop through all questions
  foreach ($questions as $questionIndex => $questionText) {
    // User's answer is -1, which means "did not answer"
    $usersAnswer = -1;

    // If the user did answer though, save the user's answer index
    if (isset($_POST['question'][$questionIndex])) {
      $usersAnswer = intval($_POST['question'][$questionIndex]);
    }

    // Now we output text - did not answer / correct / incorrect
    if ($usersAnswer === -1) {
      echo "<p>Question $questionIndex - You forgot to answer this question!</p>";
    } elseif ($usersAnswer === $correct[$questionIndex]) {
      echo "<p>Question $questionIndex - Correct!</p>";
    } else {
      echo "<p>Question $questionIndex - Incorrect!</p>";
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

Look how easy you can make it afterwards:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Quiz</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
/* REPLACE THIS LINE WITH DEFINITION OF VARIABLES $questions, $answers, $correct */

/* REPLACE THIS LINE WITH ALL THE FUNCTIONS */

// Main part of the code follows

// If there is the 'question' field in POST form, it means the user submitted the quiz
if (isset($_POST['question'])) {
    // Prepare and send e-mail
    $messageSubject = $_POST['studentname'];
    $to = "example@example.com";
    $body = emailBody($questions, $answers, $correct);
    $headers = "From: marcindybka@marcindybka.com" . "\r\n";
    mail($to,$messageSubject,$body,$headers);

    // Make a report of user's answers
    htmlReport($questions, $correct);
} else {
    // If the quiz was not submitted yet, let's encourage the user to do so :)
    echo "<p>Please take the quiz.</p>";
}   
?>
        <hr>
        <?php generateHtml($questions, $answers) ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now you are using values directly from the comboboxes (problem #2) and you can include score wherever you can call the function "score()" (problem #1).

Hope this answers it... Please remind me if there is any error in the code or something essential missing in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tommander!! It all looks great, I have a feeling it is looking great :), cause I don’t know exactly how to use it, i mean as I said earlier I am at a beginner’s level :(. Thanks a lot for the entire code once again, I will have to now study it, cause I don’t want to just copy and paste, but instead, I would like to be able to understand the code you’ve written. At first I am trying to understand how you came up with the array, it is a multidimensional one and it is difficult for me to see what arrays are inside of other arrays :( as far as I see it…

Comment: looks like you have created a variable called quiz ($quiz) and you have assigned an array of arrays into this variable. So this array consists of two elements from which one is called ‘question’ and the other called ‘answers’ consists yet another elements which are arrays of two elements called ‘answer1’ and ‘true/or false’, ‘answer2’ and ‘true/or false’, and ‘answer3’ and ‘true/false’.(????) I am not sure if it makes any sense what I am writing in here cause I feel like Ive lost it, that array of arrays of other arrays.

Comment: Is there any way you could explained me these multidimensional arrays so that I would understand it better and start actually seeing it? Maybe you could share some links that I could go over to get a better understanding of that. Once I get it I will be able to move onto functions. I need take it step by step otherwise I don’t get it and it is really frustrating . Anyway, thank you I once again I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Longus200, I absolutely love your attitude, therefore sorry for “throwing” this solution at you without much explanation. I would say it’s good to start with official PHP docs regarding arrays < https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php>. It’s true that the structure of the array I made up could be a little confusing and that’s on me. So I’ll try to explain it and I hope, along with the docs, you will get the idea of it better. If not, please let me know and we’ll find a way to simplify it, while still keeping the advantages. (next comment follows)

Comment: So you can imagine an array as a table with two columns - key (which can be a string or int) and value (which can be basically anything). If you have an array $myArray = [“Hello”, “World”], you are just writing values and letting PHP assign keys to these values starting from 0. So the same array can be created as $myArray = [0 => “Hello”, 1 => “World”]. The difference is just that now you *explicitly* said, what key a value has. And accessing a value in an array is e.g. $myArray[0], which is “Hello”. And I said that the value can be anything, which means it can be an array, too. So imagine…

Comment: … you put an array into the value of an array. $myArray[1] = [“I am”, “Groot”]. Take a piece of paper and draw a table. First row will have 0 and “Hello”, second row will have 1 and another table. That table has two rows. First row has 0 and “I am” and other is 1 and “Groot”. So if you get lost, try this way. Now to that array $quiz. We start with array that has 0,1,… as key and  array as value. That array has two keys - “question” with string value and “answers” with array. That array has keys 0,1,… and value array. That array has key 0 with answer and key 1 bool (if answer is correct).

Comment: In a while I will add an alternative to the answer that will be much easier.

Comment: thanks for all of you comments and for the link to php docs. I will have to study now, and will definitely

Comment: get back to you when I come up with that array code storing my quiz questions with answers. I will also let you know if I get stuck and don't know how to do a thing hoping you would give me a hint. Thanks again for all explanation.

Comment: I edited the answer and added some comments, also I tried the code on my PC, so now I know it works if you use it. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Anyway, feel free to get back with any questions :) Good luck and congrats to your achievements so far!

Comment: Thank you a thousand! I've gone over your code and it's awesome, the way you did the changes to it and how you structured it now, plus the comments, you have no idea how helpful it is, it's clear now, I also did some studies and got a better understanding of some concepts, I really really appreciate that!! It is huge motivation to see that the code is working, plus to see it can be done in such a logical and clear way. I'm amazed with the level of your skills plus the way you are explaining things.

Comment: Once again million thanks and I will definitely give you a hallo when I get stuck again,  hoping you won't mind. Best regards!

Comment: Happy to help you and good luck. Follow-up questions can be separated from this question, so others can benefit from it, too :)

Comment: Hi Tommander, I thought uou could maybe help me with this one. I use explode in my php code to load the strings from a txt file into an array. The strings are loaded into array with no problem, however, the first element has an index 0 but I want it to have an index 1. How do I achieve that? I appreciate any ideas cause I'm feeling stuck with no solution nor any ideas:(

Comment: Hi @longus200, you can use something like this:
`$array = ['one', 'two', 'three']; for ($i=1; $i <= 3; $i++) { echo $array[$i-1]; }`

Comment: However, I highly recommend getting used to counting items in an array starting with zero, because that is a standard so to say. If you have any particular use case where this makes you some trouble, post it. It's better to talk having something particular to discuss :)

Answer (score 0):

at first i recommended you to look into php arrays and how to loop them.
This will make your code look shorter, cleaner and easier.
I am sorry, but the code is a little mess and its hard to implement your features in it.

Comment: thank you for writing a comment anyway,  I know my code is a mess I'm fully aware of it. I'm a beginner and trying to learn, I found programming crazy fascinating and want to learn but it's difficult sometimes to find level-appropriate resources so that you don't get frustrated if things don't work out. On the other side, it's a very satisfying feeling if your code is working I mean is doing something even when it is messy, and you do know this but still guess what,  wow!

Comment: I'm super excited because the code is doing something, although it's not exactly in 100% doing everything I intended it to do but still if this is one of your very first tries you may feel happy about it. Thanks again! I will study little more and try to come up with a cleaner code.

Comment: Great to you want to learn it!
I would love to see your new improved version in a while here!
Your attitude is great! Wish best success